# How to exclude cancelled good receipt P.O

Tags: sapb1

I want to exclude all cancelled good receipt P.O and incorporate in this below query. The `InQTY` is showing all the cancelled GRPO as well.

`/*select T0."DocDate" from OINM T0 where T0."DocDate">=[%0] and T0."DocDate"<=[%1] */`

`select DISTINCT T1."ItemCode" ,T1."ItemName",T2."WhsCode",`

`(Select IFNULL((Sum("InQty"-"OutQty")),0) from OINM where "DocDate" < [%0] and "ItemCode"=T0."ItemCode" and "Warehouse" = T2."WhsCode") as "Opening Qty",`

`(select IFNULL ((Sum("InQty")),0) From OINM where "DocDate">=[%0] and "DocDate"<=[%1] and "ItemCode"=T0."ItemCode" and "Warehouse" = T2."WhsCode" ) as "Receipt Qty",`

`((select IFNULL((Sum("OutQty")),0) From OINM where "DocDate">=[%0] and "DocDate"<=[%1] and "ItemCode"=T0."ItemCode" and "Warehouse" = T2."WhsCode" and "TransType"='67'))as "Issue Qty",`

`(Select IFNULL((Sum("InQty"-"OutQty")),0) from OINM where "DocDate" <=[%1] and "ItemCode"=T0."ItemCode" and "Warehouse" = T2."WhsCode" ) as "Closing Qty"`

`FROM OINM T0 INNER JOIN OITM T1 ON T0."ItemCode" = T1."ItemCode"LEFT JOIN OWHS T2 ON T0."Warehouse" = T2."WhsCode" WHERE T2."WhsCode" = '[%2]'Group by T1."ItemCode" ,T1."ItemName",T2."WhsCode",T0."ItemCode"ORDER BY T1."ItemCode"`

Answer (score 0):

The Goods Receipt P.O Table has a field *CANCELED* which will either be a 'Y' or and 'N'

```
SELECT 
Docentry  
FROM OPDN
where CANCELED = 'N'
```

Comment: If you could include this code in the above query, I would be grateful. Thanks

Comment: personally I would rewrite the query.  joining the specific document tables rather than trying to do everything from the journal entry table or you will have to handle each transaction type separately.